When microk8s is deployed, container images cannot be pulled from private registry mirror
When microk8s is deployed, container images cannot be pulled from private registry mirror（use harbor）。error information below：
Failed to pull image "docker.io/calico/cni:v3.25.1": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/calico/cni:v3.25.1": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:d8c39dc08ef22a070c56e198bd5c5f6c04a5823c8ed47c83fe4e7c5d45df3df6: not found
enter image description here
It's the same issue whether you're using https or using http
however ，It is normal to use docker or microk8s ctr to pull the image directly：
enter image description here
It is normal to use docker or microk8s ctr to pull the image directly, and although the image can be pulled normally in this way, I found that(microk8s ctr command) the download rate of container images is very slow, and theoretically, the intranet speed should be very fast, close to gigabit
My lab environment is：
OS：ubuntu server 24.04
harbor version is v2.11.2-201d421d
microk8s version is V1.31.3
use Windows CA issue certificate
# custom launch configuration for MicroK8s
---
version: 0.1.0
extraKubeletArgs:
  --cluster-domain: dltornado2.com
  --cluster-dns: 10.152.183.10
addons:
  - name: dns
  - name: hostpath-storage
  - name: ingress
  - name: nvidia
  - name: observability
containerdRegistryConfigs:
  # Use `https://harbor.dltornado2.com/dockerhub_proxy` as a DockerHub registry mirror.
  docker.io: |
    [host."harbor.dltornado2.com/dockerhub_proxy"]
    capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  #  override_path = true
  #  ca = "/home/ubuntu/certs.d/docker.io/ca.crt"
  # Use `https://hub.geekery.cn` as a DockerHub registry mirror.
  #docker.io: |
  #  [host."https://hub.geekery.cn"]
  #  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  #  override_path = true
  # Use `https://harbor.dltornado2.com/quay_proxy` as a quay registry mirror.
  quay.io: |
    [host."https://harbor.dltornado2.com/quay_proxy"]
    capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  #  override_path = true
  #  ca = "/home/ubuntu/certs.d/quay.io/ca.crt"
  # Use `https://registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers` as a gcr registry mirror.
  registry.k8s.io: |
    [host."https://k8s.m.daocloud.io"]
    capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  #  override_path = true
  #  ca = "/home/ubuntu/certs.d/registry.k8s.io/ca.crt"
  #registry.k8s.io: |
  #  [host."https://k8s.m.daocloud.io"]
  #  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  #registry.k8s.io: |
  #  [host."https://registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers"]
  #  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  #Containerd will use this proxy when pulling images from the upstream repositories

harbor configuration is:
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
It took me a week and it still didn't solve the problem。
